# No automatic line break after </p> tag?

Tags: html, css

Previously my HTML, after the "< /p>" tag, would have a line break and also leave a blank line following ready for the next paragraph. However, this has stopped happening.

This is the CSS for my paragraphs:

```
p, a, li, form, input {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @jBot-42 that question you linked is asking how to display `<p>` elements `inline` this question is about `margin` values for `<p>` elements. Not really sure this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "automatic" `<br>` after `<p>` tags. What you are seeing (as the "blank line") is the `margin-bottom` value. If there is no "blank line" under your `p` tags, there is likely little to no `margin-bottom` value.

This will add some space under your `<p>` elements; adjust to taste.

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```